# ES6 class context in NodeJs? Or using 'this' inside a class in NodeJs?'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, static-methods

I am new to node js and i am actually not able to understand how to call methods inside a class except statically or by creating a new object each time i'm iterating over functions.

This is kind of crazy. For example:

```
class UserController 
{
    methodOne (req, res) {
        this.methodTwo (req);
    }

    methodTwo (data) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

That's how i want to call my function but, every time i do this, I end up with error of `this` is undefined.

I know `fat arrow functions` don't follow the same context like in javascript. But i just wanna make sure if i'm doing it right or not.

And that's how i achieve above code.

```
class UserController 
{
    static methodOne (req, res) {
        UserController.methodTwo (req);
    }

    static methodTwo (data) {
        // Manipulates request before calling
        return UserController.methodThree (data);
    }

    static methodThree (data) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

i.e. calling each method statically with class name `UserController`.

So if there's any better way to do it, I need you to suggest.
Thanks in advance.

**P.S: Above code is just an example guys.**

Comment: But it doesn't work because `this` is undefined. IDK how to bind `this` to this class.

Comment: No. i'm simply iterating over methods inside a single class. No inheritance, nothing.

Comment: there is no need to use  `async` keywork on a function declaration if that function doesn't have the `await` keyword in its body.

Comment: It was just an example.

Comment: `async` It's completely irrelevant to your question, why complicate things?

Comment: I am new to node and javascipt. And async is not my problem right now. Thank you.

Comment: @anshcarter *but, every time i do this* - every time you do what? Where is methodOne called? The question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Snippet 1 and 2 are oranges and apples. Instance and static methods are different things. Static-only class is antipattern. This means that a class isn't needed here.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your problem is that you lost the function context

```
class UserController {
  async methodOne() {
    return this.methodTwo()
  }

  async methodTwo() {
    return Promise.resolve("methodtwo")
  }
}

const obj = new UserController();
const methodOne = obj.methodOne;

methodOne(); // ----> This will throw the Error

methodOne.call(obj); // ----> This Works

// Or you can call the method directly from the obj
obj.methodOne(); // Works!!

// If you want to cache the method in a variable and preserve its context use `bind()`
const methodOneBound = obj.methodOne.bind(obj);
methodOneBound(); // ----> This works
```